# How to use VistaDB in multiuser environment

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, remobjects, vistadb

My requirement is as written below:
I have a DotNet(c#) winform application using VistaDB as database. So to support multiuser environment( as VistaDB is serverless Database) I have decided to implement Remobjects SDK to build a server which will service all the database queries and the clients will just call the service. I am using Entity Framework as an ORM. Now how to pass entities between server and clients? Are there any other solutions available. I don't want to use WCF.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this as I would like to implement something similar.